# OPENXML in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Declare @XMLData as nvarchar(max) 
set @XMLData = 
'<operation>
    <operationstatus>Success</operationstatus>
    <message>WorkOrder Details Retrieved Successfully for the WorkOrderID: 25</message>
    <Details>
      <propname key="workorderid">25</propname>
      <propname key="requester">Rahul</propname>
      <propname key="subject">NEW REQUEST</propname>
    </Details>
  </operation>'
```

My output should be

```
wororderid requester subject 
   25      Rahul     NEW REQUEST
```

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @doc INT

EXEC SP_XML_PREPAREDOCUMENT @doc output, @XmlData

SELECT workorderid, requester,subject INTO #Tempdetails FROM OPENXML(@doc,'/operation/Details/propname/key',2) 
WITH 
( 
workorderid INT, requester NVARCHAR(250), 
subject NVARCHAR(250) ) 
SELECT workorderid,requester,subject FROM #Tempdetails
```

Comment: Struggling to see what the question is here

Answer (score 1):

First of all - it is looks like XML, smells like XML, and quacks like XML - **make it `XML`!** (and **not** `NVARCHAR(MAX)`)

```
Declare @XMLData as XML = 
'<operation>
    <operationstatus>Success</operationstatus>
    <message>WorkOrder Details Retrieved Successfully for the WorkOrderID: 25</message>
    <Details>
      <propname key="workorderid">25</propname>
      <propname key="requester">Rahul</propname>
      <propname key="subject">NEW REQUEST</propname>
    </Details>
  </operation>'
```

Second: I would recommend to use the native XQuery support in SQL Server rather than the clunky, messy, hard to handle old `OPENXML` stuff - in that case, this statement will retrieve the data you're interested in:

```
SELECT
    WorkOrderId = @XMLData.value('(/operation/Details/propname[@key="workorderid"])[1]', 'int'),
    Requester = @XMLData.value('(/operation/Details/propname[@key="requester"])[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    [Subject] = @XMLData.value('(/operation/Details/propname[@key="subject"])[1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

**Update:** if your XML has multiple `<Details>` nodes, then you'd need to use a call to the `.nodes()` function to get a list of those `<Details>` nodes, and the `.value()` call need to be adapted to reach into the individual `<Details>` nodes to fetch the properties:

```
SELECT
    WorkOrderId = Details.value('(propname[@key="workorderid"])[1]', 'int'),
    Requester = @XMLData.value('(propname[@key="requester"])[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    [Subject] = @XMLData.value('(propname[@key="subject"])[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    @XMLData.nodes('/operation/Details') AS XTbl(Details)
```

Comment: what if details has multiple nodes

Declare @XMLData as XML = 
'<operation>
    <operationstatus>Success</operationstatus>
    <message>WorkOrder Details Retrieved Successfully for the WorkOrderID: 25</message>
    <Details>
      <propname key="workorderid">25</propname>
      <propname key="requester">Rahul</propname>
      <propname key="subject">NEW REQUEST</propname>
    </Details>
<Details>
      <propname key="workorderid">26</propname>
      <propname key="requester">Mikel</propname>
      <propname key="subject">UPDATE REQUEST</propname>
    </Details>
  </operation>'

Comment: @user3071287: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.